# Map iterator not deferencable

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have to find in `mytextmap` the closest value to `keymap`, for all `keymap`'s elements and attach it to each other in a new `map <char, char>` called `key`(key of `key` is key of `keymap`, value is key of `mytextmap`).

Here my attempt:

```
for (auto i = keymap.begin(); i != keymap.end();){
    int j = ((i->second) / sumkey)*sum;
    auto tmp = find_value(mytextmap.begin(), mytextmap.end(), j);
    while (tmp->second != j)
    {
        j--;
        tmp = find_value(mytextmap.begin(), mytextmap.end(), j);
    }
    key[(*tmp).second] = i->second;
    i=keymap.erase(i);
    mytextmap.erase(tmp);
}
```

find_value - returns an itterator for element in (map.begin(), map.end()) with value(like j in my code).

There is an error, somewhere. Crash error: "expression map/set iterator not dereferencable.
Problem is not in erase(already fixed).  On while-line it crahes. Sting before works, string after - no.

Comment: You're invalidating your iterator by removing it from the map.

Comment: Is there any way to remove an element with some itterator? I need 2 find an element, attach them, and them made them removed from my maps.

Comment: Sure. Use `i = keymap.erase(i);` and don't increment the iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the line

```
keymap.erase(i);
```

the iterator, `i`, is invalid.

Try:

```
for (auto i = keymap.begin(); i != keymap.end(); )
{
   int j = ((i->second) / sumkey)*sum;
   auto tmp = find_value(mytextmap.begin(), mytextmap.end(), j);
   while (tmp->second != j)
   {
      j--;
      tmp = find_value(mytextmap.begin(), mytextmap.end(), j);
   }
   key[(*tmp).second] = i->second;
   auto next = i;
   std::advance(next, 1);
   keymap.erase(i);
   i = next;
   mytextmap.erase(tmp);
}
```

If you are using a C++11 compiler, you can use:

```
for (auto i = keymap.begin(); i != keymap.end(); )
{
   int j = ((i->second) / sumkey)*sum;
   auto tmp = find_value(mytextmap.begin(), mytextmap.end(), j);
   while (tmp->second != j)
   {
      j--;
      tmp = find_value(mytextmap.begin(), mytextmap.end(), j);
   }
   key[(*tmp).second] = i->second;
   i = keymap.erase(i);
   mytextmap.erase(tmp);
}
```

**Update, in response to OP's comment**

I think the problem lies in the lines:

```
   while (tmp->second != j)
   {
      j--;
      tmp = find_value(mytextmap.begin(), mytextmap.end(), j);
   }
   key[(*tmp).second] = i->second;
```

What happens when `tmp == mytextmap.end()`?

I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish in those lines. I suggest you add some checks that make sure that you don't access `tmp` when `tmp == mytextmap.end()`.

Comment: and so it still doesn't work. Same mistake.

Comment: @MishaTihonov, did you make sure to remove the `++i` in the `for` line?

Comment: @R Sahu  so now ive just copied ur code to be sure. Still nothing.

Comment: @R Sahu, it crashes on while-line. Before erasing.

Comment: @MishaTihonov, that makes sense now. See my update.

Comment: @R Sahu, yeap, ure right. I had mistake there. Just changed my while into      while (tmp == mytextmap.end()) and now it works. Thank you!